# Kaplan-Meier, survival analysis and plots in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, survival

What is the best package to to do some survival analysis and plots in R? I have tried some tutorials but I couldn't find a definite answer.

TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try CRAN Task View: http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/views/Survival.html

Answer (score 12):

I think that it's fair to say that the [survival](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/) package is the "recommended" package in general, as it's included in base R (i.e. does not need to be installed separately).  There are many good tutorials online for this.  But you need to be more specific to get a more specific answer.

Comment: could you provide a link to what you feel is the best tutorial that you've seen using R and survival?

Answer (score 9):

In an article in *The American Statistician*, Wolkewitz *et al.* use packages *Epi*, *mvna*, and *survival*.  See *Two Pitfalls in Survival Analyses of Time-Dependent Exposure: A Case Study in a Cohort of Oscar Nominees*, v. 64 no. 3 (August 2010) pp 205-211.  This exposition introduces multistate survival models and focuses on the use of a "Lexis diagram" to assess possible forms of bias.

Answer (score 0):

Survival plots have never been so informative with 
http://www.r-bloggers.com/survival-plots-have-never-been-so-informative/